# javax.websocket.DeploymentException: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer

Tags: websocket, osgi, tyrus

I am trying to create a websocket using the tyrus project. I am getting this below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer

    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.<init>(ClientManager.java:272) ~[bundlefile:na]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.createClient(ClientManager.java:240) ~[bundlefile:na]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.createClient(ClientManager.java:219) ~[bundlefile:na]
```

My pom dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Very simple java code :

```
    logger.info("Creating web socket for url {}", getWebSocketUrl(currentApic.IPAddress, port));
    echoUri = new URI(getWebSocketUrl(currentApic.IPAddress, port));
    client = ClientManager.createClient();
    client.connectToServer(APICWebClient.class, echoUri);
```

if i try to add the container dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

My mvn clean install fails saying :

```
 Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-server:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-server:pom:1.4 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): repo1.maven.org: unknown error: Unknown host repo1.maven.org: unknown error -> [Help 1]
```

**Edited: The above issue is resolved after mvn clean. server container and client container packages are added. but still i am getting the same runtime error
    java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer**

I am using the in OSGi environment. How do i solve this. need some help on this.

Comment: For the last issue, Unknown host repo1.maven.org, resolved by doing mvn clean and mvn clean install

Answer (score 7):

The container `org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer` is missing on classpath.
Add the maven module `tyrus-container-grizzly-client`.

And yes, the exception thrown by tyrus might be more accurate.

Comment: i have tried adding that also. But still the same error

Comment: Make sure you added `tyrus-container-grizzly-client`, not `tyrus-container-grizzly`.

Answer (score 0):

use,


org.glassfish.tyrus
tyrus-container-grizzly-client
1.17

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).